# Convert foreach into map function in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This is my function in foreach loop for creating object which has property and value as word and its count, but i want to convert it in map according to es6

```
function harmlessRamsonNote(noteText,magazineText)
{
  var noteArr = noteText.split(' ');
  var magazineArr = magazineText.split(' ');
  var magazineObj = {};

  magazineArr.forEach(word => {
    if(!magazineObj[word])
    {
      magazineObj[word] = 0;
    }
    magazineObj[word]++;
  });

  console.log(magazineObj);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
magazineArr.map((word, index, array) => {
   !magazineObj[word] ? magazineObj[word] = 0 : magazineObj[word]++;
})
```

Answer (score 2):

`map` will return an new item for each item. Instead you can use `reduce`.

```
const magazineObj = magazineArr.reduce((acc,word) => {
   acc[word] = (acc[word] || -1) + 1;
}, {});
```

Comment: it gives error as magazineObj not defined in this line
magazineObj[word] = (magazineObj[word] || -1) + 1;

Comment: It still give error as
     acc[word] = (acc[word] || -1) + 1;
                     ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'is' of undefined
I think its because in first loop value of acc is undefined though i am not sure of this anyways
i really appreciate your help and response though

Comment: I have not worked with `is`, maybe it is your error?

Comment: When i call the function with this
harmlessRamsonNote('','this is the ramson the the text');
it gives that error, i.e gives error in second word of passed string